# How to add inner elements from stream to stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I have class `Warehouse` that hold List of Different boxes, that placed here.
Boxes can have boxes inside, in this case their id starts with "big" and their List consist of "small" boxes

```
class Warehouse{
    private List<Box> boxes;
}
class Box {
    private String id;
    private List<Box> innerBoxes;
}
```

next method return `Stream` of `Box`es that are on `Warehouse`.

```
public Stream<Box> getBoxes();
```

How I can get all Boxes, that are one Warehouse and in "big" boxes?
I tried next way

```
public Stream<Box> getAllBoxes(){
    return getBoxes().stream().filter(b -> b.getId().startsWith("big"));
}
```

Buts it returna only inner boxes, how to collect inner and big boxes in one stream?

Comment: What's the `Boxes` class? Is it supposed to be `Box`? If not, please show the `Box` class.

Comment: Why do people always insist of doing everything in streams? Why not simply create a list out of two existing lists of the same elements? You know how to do *that*, right?

Comment: By the way, I think it is nice that you can distinguish between "big" and "small" boxes by ID, but I think there is something wrong with the object model if that kind of thing is not reflected in the class design. *Just* having a different ID seems wrong to me (and the fact that you can create a "big" box without any boxes in it is probably the proof of that).

Comment: @Maarten - reinstate Monica Unfortunatelly I got this structure not by my wish

Comment: My comments above do not invalidate your question or any answer that uses streams to merge two lists together, I was just pointing out how the issue could be largely avoided and how to create a more robust class design, without the possibility of invalid state. Yes, sometimes (quite often) you have to work with what you're given; refactoring is not always warranted.

Comment: It is unclear to me if you allow a "big box" inside a "big box", matryoshka style. Also, do you want to include the big boxes or are they unpacked and dismissed? Sorry about the large number of comments; they are about separate issues though.

Comment: If it's that model and nothing else, Reger05's answer ought to do it. But as pointed out, either your model doesn't make sense or your question doesn't. Why would you want to list inner and outer boxes on equal footing ?

Comment: Big box can contain only small box, and assignment for me is return stream looks like: big1, 1,2,3(//all in big1), big2(//empty), big3, 4,5,6(//in big3)

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica, i'm agree with you, but you are talking about the way of thinking. for my point the objective of the issue is to know the feasibility with stream.

Comment: @Khilarian If in your example "big1, 1,2,3(//all in big1), big2(//empty), big3, 4,5,6(//in big3)" are all objects in one stream not just a stream of the big object then my answer below will work. The concatenation of the collections into a stream of a Depth First Search of your data structure.

Your Box objects are essentially a tree structure. Converting this to a stream will flatten that structure to be iterated over. The answer below will build a stream that contains every box in the warehouse. You can filter from there.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to collect both inner and big boxes in on stream you can use stream.of() and stream.concat();

```
public Stream<Box> flattened() {
        return Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(this),
                innerBoxes.stream().flatMap(Box::flattened));
    }
```

More info on this can be found here
http://squirrel.pl/blog/2015/03/04/walking-recursive-data-structures-using-java-8-streams/

Once that method exists in your Box class you can call

```
warehouse.boxes.stream().flatMap(Box::flattened); //Collect as needed
```